# Using a hidden div for layout purposes

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I was just wondering if there was any disadvantages for having empty divs in place in order to have a layout that I desire. Is there any other way around having hidden divs because I know that it adds to messy code.

See images below for what I am trying to demonstrate:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the bullet points on the left are level with the h2 element but when I add a h2 element before the bullet points, it lowers them to the level of the paragraph (which is how I want it). Obviously I can make this h2 element invisible and therefore achieve my desired effect but is there more of a professional way of doing this?

Comment: You can add a `margin-top: 50px;` with the right amount of pixels

Comment: of course you can!! Omg such a blonde moment haha. Thanks mate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But why you want to do that? Whats `margin-top` property for?

I'll go lil brief here, you should first learn `floats` than go for `positioning`, also learn what `block` and `inline` elements are, you got a lot of CSS things out there, `margins,`paddings` etc, take a look at [box-model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) too so that you don't pull your hair later

And if you want to stick to a dirty markup than empty `div's` and `br` are options for you, but you won't get a specific height from top using `br` so for that you need to use an empty div but DON'T USE THIS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add extra space without CSS, you can use `<br/>`
 tags - its definitely a much better than empty divs, which is messy and a bad practice.

CSS is really the best way, though.

Give the h2 a width so it takes up the entire rest of the row. The bullet list will then automatically drop to the same height as the left paragraphs.
Or, give the bullet list a margin-top or padding-top.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions which will provide a quick fix:

1. Margin-top on the bullet points element or.
2. Add an H2 with a non-breaking space inside it e.g.

   ```
    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use either `margin-top` for the second div or `margin-bottom` for the first one.

Example: If the hidden div's height is 100px, you better write: `<div style="margin-bottom:100px">...</div>`